# r - Can dplyr::group_by work with sf::st_intersects

Tags: r, grouping, sf, st-intersects

Trying to combine `dplyr::group_by` and `sf::st_intersects` to see which of the objects within groups in a sf dataframe are intersecting with each other but in the end all objects are compared with all objects in the dataframe irrespective of the groups.

It would be very useful if there is another option `package/baseR` to do this and limit the comparison of objects within the dataframe and only within a specified group.

Below I have done:
1. create a `LINESTRING` and a `POLYGON`
2. used `sf::st_intersection` to find parts of `LINESTRING` in the `POLYGON`
3. convert to `LINESTRING`
4. check which of the `LINESTRING`s are intersecting with each other

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# sample data
poly <- data.frame(lon = c(-3.5, -1.5, -1.5, -0.5, -0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 7, 7, -3.5, -3.5),
               lat = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,1,1,0, 0, 2, 2, 0),
               var = 1) %>%
st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% group_by(var) %>%
summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = F) %>% st_cast("POLYGON")

line <- data.frame(lon = c(-4, -3, -2, -2, -3, 2, 2.5, 2, 2), lat = c(0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1), var = 1) %>%
st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% group_by(var) %>%
summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = F) %>% 
st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")

# calculating intersection of line with polygon
inters <- st_intersection(line,poly) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
inters <- inters %>% mutate(var = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

# trying to see which of the linestrings intersect with each other
inters$flag <- inters %>% group_by(var) %>% st_intersects()
```

This should calculate the intersections between the first two `LINESTRING`s separately and between the last 9 `LINESTRING`s separately. So intersections of the first `LINESTRING` with any of the `LINESTRING`s from 3 to 11 shouldn`t be calculated.

Comment: Does `tidyr::nest()` help any? I tried `inters %>% group_by(var) %>% tidyr::nest() %>% mutate(flag = purrr::map(data, st_intersects))` and returned the same result as using `sapply()` in @sebdalgarno's answer (expect the data are split into two rows of the tibble).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, using lapply and split instead of group_by:

```
inters$flag <- sapply(split(inters, inters$var), function(x) st_intersects(x)) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "base R"? Base does not support piping,  this is a dpylr syntax appled to a sf function and object. Just because it is wrapped in lapply and split does not make it limited to base operators.

Comment: I just mean its an alternative to `group_by`. Sure, there are some pipes in there